# Ignore ssl certificate requests in webview

Tags: android, webview

I make small app which involve [aspx pages](https://noor.moe.gov.sa/) , I try open it throw my webview I got blank screen .

I try open it with chrome browser it give me certificate needed

[image]

my code is very simple I add some documentation to explain what is going on

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            urlSite = bundle.getString("passed_url");
        }
     _toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    _toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    // enable javascript
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            new ParseURl().execute(new String[]{urlSite});
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    if(urlSite != null){
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl(urlSite);
       // webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/af.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the error message, it's going nothing to do with your code and everything to do with the name (URL) of the site not matching the name of the security certificate. Change one or the other to make them match.

Comment: all I need how to ignore this dialog and I figure how to do that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research I found the answer, just override `onReceivedSslError` method and skip it.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```