# How to render a secure https url in react native webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, react-native

I am trying to load a secured https URL in react native Webview but its showing blank white screen and not throwing any error in console as well.  Plus on the same Page, I am able to load all other https URLs like `https://www.facebook.com/`, `https://www.google.com/`.

I am using:

```
"react-native": "0.59.4"
```

```
<WebView 
  source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/login?user=xxxxxxxxxx&pass=xxxxxx'}}
  scalesPageToFit={true}
  style={{ height: 500, width: 500}}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  startInLoadingState={true}
  ignoreSslError={true}
  onError={(err) => console.log('error', err)}
/>
```

It should load the webpage like in the browser.

Comment: is this URL is independently running on browser?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in the browser.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416096/android-webview-not-loading-an-https-url There Might be an issue regarding SSL. Try this another URL, not google.com or youTube

Comment: Especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47635290/7124761) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34334206/7124761) answer

Comment: I solved this issue. There was a problem with server setup. Thank you for the help. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Done! happy coding!